# How to use `apply` in python without specifying the column name of the data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, python-dateutil

I am trying to use `apply` function on a data frame to remove strings from the date columns. For instance, I have a data frame below and I want to remove the strings from `Start` and `Finish` columns using `dateutil` package without specifying the column names.

```
df=[["1/5/2020 Yes", "5/9/2020 String",2,6],["1/8/2020 No","5/8/2020 sponge",8,9],["8/9/2020 Spine","5/8/2020 spike",8,9]]
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df.columns=["Start","Finish","x1","x2"]
```

Here is my trial, but it is not working and throwing `KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)`

```
df[0] = df[0].apply(dparser.parse,fuzzy=True)
df[1] = df[1].apply(dparser.parse,fuzzy=True)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df[0]` access the column *named* `0`, which is not in your dataframe. You want to give the correct name, i.e. `df['Start']` or use `iloc`: `df.iloc[:,0]`.

Also, another way to extract the date is to use `regex` pattern, for example:

```
for i in range(2):
    df.iloc[:,i] = df.iloc[:,i].str.extract('^(\S+)')[0]
```

Output:

```
      Start    Finish  x1  x2
0  1/5/2020  5/9/2020   2   6
1  1/8/2020  5/8/2020   8   9
2  8/9/2020  5/8/2020   8   9
```